# How to use find to list all files except those under .git?

Tags: macos, zsh

I want to find a list of file (no directories) excluding those under `.git`

I am trying out some suggested `find` syntax to achieve as suggested in this SO question:

https://superuser.com/questions/397307/how-to-ignore-certain-filenames-using-find

Here are what I attempted

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.git*' 

find . \( -type f  -prune -o \! -name '*git*' \)
find . \( -type f  -prune -o \! -name *git* \)
find . \( -type f  -prune -o ! -name *git* \)
```

But the output always contains files in `.git`. Here is a partial listing

```
.
./.coveragerc
./.DS_Store
./.git/.DS_Store
./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
./.git/config
./.git/FETCH_HEAD
./.git/HEAD
./.git/hooks
./.git/hooks/disable-commit-msg
./.git/hooks/pre-push
./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
./.git/index
./.git/info
./.git/info/exclude
./.git/info/refs
./.git/logs
./.git/logs/HEAD
./.git/logs/refs
./.git/logs/refs/heads
./.git/logs/refs/heads/1312
```

The version OS X is El Capitan‎, and I am using `zsh`. `find` is located in `/usr/bin`

Is it an OS X `find` issue? If so, how can I achieve my intended result?

**EDIT**

I tried this command

```
find . \( -type d -name '.git' -o -type f  \)  -prune
```

and it is closer to what I want. However in the output I can still see the folder `.git`

Comment: Quick fix: `find . | grep -v '^\./\.git'`

Comment: The examples in the linked question don't prune or have -o or have \( so where did they come from - + *git* will match more than you want

Comment: Agreed the accepted answer is not correct but use -wholename as per comments

Comment: I got this from the second answer but I haven't placed them in right order I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct but with a comment it starts you off.

To get no html files

```
find . -type f   ! -name '*.html'
```

-name loks at the file part of the path for the whole path you need --wholename so

```
find . -type f  ! -wholename '*/.git/*' ! -name '*.html'
```

So only get files (-type) ignore the .git directory - note you need to enter the directory delimiters and the . or else you remove files like .gitconfig which are valid ones

OK this looks at all file -prune might look at less but the speed probably does not matter it is better as in all code to get an understandable working thing first